# GatsbyJS Index.js component throws an Invalid Hook Call error, I'm pretty sure my code is correct (mostly)

Tags: reactjs, npm

So on my friend's mac computer, using the exact same src files and the same package.json file, this code runs perfectly. I tried npm ls react and it shows I indeed have two references, but npm deduped one of them. I'm also quite certain my call is legal.

```
const IndexPage = () => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(CORONAVIRUS_QUERY)
    if (loading) return <span>loading...</span>
    if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>

    return (
        <Layout>
            <SEO title='Home' />
            <h2>I've got the high ground, and now so do you</h2>
            <DataTable regionData={data} />
            <Link to='/about/'>About</Link>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default IndexPage
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
    "private": true,
    "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": "null pointer studios",
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
        "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
        "gatsby": "^2.19.45",
        "gatsby-image": "^2.2.44",
        "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.48",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.41",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.24",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.4.13",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.56",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.19",
        "graphql": "^14.6.0",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "nivo": "^0.31.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
        "react-materialize": "^3.5.9",
        "reactable": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "^1.19.1"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "gatsby"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "gatsby build",
        "develop": "gatsby develop",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
        "start": "npm run develop",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean",
        "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
    },
    "prettier": {
        "singleQuote": true,
        "semi": false,
        "jsxSingleQuote": true,
        "bracketSpacing": true,
        "useTabs": true
    }
}
```

Full Error Message as Requested
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5WVm.png

EDIT: 
const [something, setsomething] = useState(0)
doesn't work either, so maybe it IS my code?

Comment: Can you show us the full error message?

Comment: yes https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5WVm.png